# Problems with FindFit-function

Tags: fitting

this it's my first question in this forum, so first hello! I have a problem with one of two datasets. With the first is everything fine and it works the way i imagined it would. With the second dataset i have the problem:

> FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {-0.995586+0.0348436
> I,-0.831975+0.0319007 I,-1.42135+0.015431 I,-0.502586+0.0348436
> I,-0.245556+0.0351842 I,-0.381265+0.0358738 I,<<39>>,0.146955
> +0.0601632 I,0.386856 +0.0558845 I,0.404713 +0.0574542 I,0.172862 +0.0514124 I,0.420545 +0.0579866 I,<<81>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {131} at {a,b,c,d,m} =
> {0.800033,1.00647,-0.775632,-6.75588,1.31064}.

My fit is written as follows:

```
fitB2 = FindFit[dataB, {d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b)^m}, {a, b, c, d, m}, x]
```

I don't understand why the Fit with my first dataset work but with the second don't. I would be very happy about any help. If you want me to be more precise, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include your data as copy-paste-able Mathematica code. Use the `{...}` icon in the Edit window to format it as code. The idea is that forum participants should be able to copy your code and data to their notebooks and experiment with it. Thanks.

Comment: You data seems to contain complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, what parameter ranges are allowed. Get best result for very high m. But is that realistic? Restrict parameters according to the model restrictions.

```
dataB = {{0.0994859, 3.2615}, {0.0931034, 2.9885}, {0.0517189, 
    2.923}, {0.0994859, 2.7685}, {0.100208, 2.524}, {0.10166, 
    2.685}, {0.0945035, 2.428}, {0.0945035, 2.761}, {0.0973349, 
    2.71}, {0.0959139, 2.5055}, {0.0945035, 2.2825}, {0.0973349, 
    2.5545}, {0.0973349, 2.5}, {0.0966231, 2.372}, {0.0973349, 
    2.6315}, {0.0980493, 2.5735}, {0.0973349, 2.835}, {0.0980493, 
    2.6955}, {0.0980493, 2.6575}, {0.0973349, 2.678}, {0.146566, 
    3.144}, {0.144821, 2.903}, {0.148321, 3.192}, {0.136254, 
    2.9815}, {0.141363, 2.9335}, {0.141363, 2.825}, {0.109078, 
    2.9375}, {0.147442, 2.992}, {0.147442, 2.7695}, {0.157254, 
    3.086}, {0.141363, 2.8365}, {0.137946, 2.7415}, {0.125507, 
    2.3935}, {0.1329, 2.673}, {0.131239, 2.6935}, {0.132068, 
    2.556}, {0.132068, 2.544}, {0.128766, 2.6725}, {0.127948, 
    2.4875}, {0.132068, 2.608}, {0.131239, 2.5805}, {0.143953, 
    2.6675}, {0.159985, 3.1545}, {0.144821, 2.7015}, {0.137099, 
    2.6015}, {0.145692, 2.9885}, {0.138796, 2.6095}, {0.141363, 
    2.643}, {0.131239, 2.675}, {0.142223, 2.6445}, {0.131239, 
    2.538}, {0.130412, 2.6085}, {0.141363, 2.6715}, {0.123892, 
    2.732}, {0.151863, 2.833}, {0.147442, 3.1955}, {0.144821, 
    2.8335}, {0.148321, 3.0065}, {0.150974, 3.4225}, {0.146566, 
    2.9595}, {0.138796, 3.039}, {0.149203, 3.177}, {0.147442, 
    3.5415}, {0.146566, 2.998}, {0.18958, 4.0825}, {0.194589, 
    4.408}, {0.190577, 4.1075}, {0.188586, 4.3735}, {0.18562, 
    4.1095}, {0.191576, 4.29}, {0.191576, 3.81}, {0.191576, 
    4.198}, {0.193582, 4.1235}, {0.184637, 4.096}, {0.18562, 
    4.16}, {0.188586, 4.0175}, {0.19661, 4.2725}, {0.187595, 
    4.225}, {0.188586, 4.182}, {0.187595, 4.1025}, {0.192578, 
    4.178}, {0.18958, 4.2235}, {0.259784, 4.0215}, {0.265642, 
    4.115}, {0.266821, 3.998}, {0.115978, 3.0375}, {0.255145, 
    3.8955}, {0.238122, 4.0265}, {0.251694, 4.154}, {0.25746, 
    4.1105}, {0.256301, 4.209}, {0.244861, 4.0355}, {0.260951, 
    3.89}, {0.260951, 4.0725}, {0.262119, 3.998}, {0.262119, 
    4.3085}, {0.255145, 3.9695}, {0.265642, 4.0945}, {0.249406, 
    4.2555}, {0.238122, 4.252}, {0.265642, 4.2435}, {0.166448, 
    3.6955}, {0.160901, 3.448}, {0.163663, 4.1145}, {0.164589, 
    3.3955}, {0.159985, 3.236}, {0.160901, 3.7775}, {0.168319, 
    4.0155}, {0.163663, 4.168}, {0.159072, 3.889}, {0.158162, 
    3.401}, {0.160901, 4.2205}, {0.162739, 4.0705}, {0.164589, 
    4.0925}, {0.164589, 4.2855}, {0.165517, 4.2445}, {0.143087, 
    3.9095}, {0.142223, 2.936}, {0.141363, 3.3965}, {0.142223, 
    2.9725}, {0.141363, 2.98}, {0.137946, 3.0195}, {0.1329, 
    2.791}, {0.129588, 3.335}, {0.132068, 3.461}, {0.127131, 
    2.9685}, {0.130412, 3.549}, {0.130412, 3.005}, {0.141363, 
    4.108}, {0.140505, 3.6295}, {0.143087, 3.02}};
```

.

```
fitB1 = FindFit[
  dataB, {d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b)^m, 
   b > 0 && a > 0 && 0 < c < 1 && d > 0 && 0 < m < 10}, {a, b, c, d, 
   m}, x, MaxIterations -> 1000, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
  Method -> NMinimize]

Plot[d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b)^m /. fitB1, {x, 0, .3}, 
 Epilog -> Point@dataB, 
 PlotRange -> Through[{Min, Max}[Transpose[dataB][[2]]]]]

fitB2 = FindFit[
  dataB, {d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b)^m, 
   b > 0 && a > 0 && 0 < c < 1 && d > 0 && 0 < m < 100}, {a, b, c, d, 
   m}, x, MaxIterations -> 1000, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
  Method -> NMinimize]

Plot[d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b)^m /. fitB2, {x, 0, .3}, 
 Epilog -> Point@dataB, 
 PlotRange -> Through[{Min, Max}[Transpose[dataB][[2]]]]]
```

Comment: +1 I don't understand the -1 vote.  This demonstrates the likely overparameterization of the model given the available data.  Using `NonlinearModelFit` allows one to obtain the parameter correlation matrix which shows that the estimators of $c$ and $m$ are nearly perfectly correlated.  Increasing the value of $m$ past 1 only has very little effect on the estimate of the error variance.